# Setting Contactless Historic Bytes in GlobalPlatform 2.3

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

In GlobalPlatform 2.2 and earlier, the API method GPSystem.setATRHistBytes allowed me to change the Historic Bytes for both contact and contactless interfaces.

However, in GlobalPlatform 2.3 that method has been altered, and now only changes the Historic Bytes for the contact interface. Those for the contactless interface remain unchanged by it.

So far, I haven't found a replacement method in any of the GlobalPlatform API packages (including the contactless extensions) which would allow me to continue changing the contactless historic bytes.

Does anyone know is this is still possible, or if not, why it has been removed from the API? I assume there must be a good reason!

Comment: Because the method name is GPSystem.setATRHistBytes not GPSystem.setATSHistBytes.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the difference between Answer To Reset for the contact interface, and Answer To Select for the contactless. In previous versions of GlobalPlatform, despite the slightly misleading name, GPSystem.setATRHistBytes sets both the Answer To Reset contact historic bytes, and the Answer To Select contactless historic bytes, in the same call. However, in GP2.3, it only sets the ATR contact bytes. Unfortunately there appears to be no equivalent method to set the contactless Answer To Select historic bytes at all. I'd like to know if this is by design, or an oversight in the 2.3 API.

Comment: I am reading GP2.3 specification, wait me.

Comment: Thanks, I have an answer to this now. There is no method in GP2.3 to set contactless historic bytes, but there is one in the JCOP 3.0.1 API (com.nxp.id.jcopx.system package). To get that package and docs, I need to register with NXP and provide a business case for it. Doing so now.

Comment: It is api only for JCOP card, it is invalid for other cards.